# How to load Gridview on dropdown selected index changed event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a `gridview` contains only a `drop down box` and `text box` controls for inputting data.I can load the dropdown on `gridview rowdatabound` event and take the input on `gridview roweditevent`.Here my question is how to load this `gridview` it self on another `dropdown selected index changed` event ,Because nothing is there to load data in to the grid in terms of gridview.datasource ,but inside gridview dropdown is loaded on `gridview rowdatabound` event.

Comment: You have to be more concrete. What do you want to do on SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: I have to load the gridview which contains another dropdown and text box for inputting data.

Comment: please show code where you some work